# passing textarea data from view to controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have a form in my `home_view.php` that uses textarea that goes like this:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>add" method="post">
        <textarea name="add-list" id="add-list" rows="10" cols="75"> </textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
    </form>
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
public function add(){
        $value = $this->input->post('add-list');
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$value'); window.location.href='".base_url()."'</script>";

        //more code here
}
```

The problem is the alert only pops up when I have a one-liner input. How can I get all the inputs of the user including new line ('\n')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nl2br function :

```
$value = nl2br($this->input->post('add-list'));
```

Comment: I'm still not able to alert the input but I'm getting the correct data anw. Thanks!

Comment: You should use htmlentities, what kind of error do you have ? or text do you have ?